# What can I backup to avoid re-downloading the updates I have installed if I am forced to erase & install Ubuntu?

Tags: upgrade, updates, backup

It's just been days since I started using Ubuntu on my PC and I'm doing my best to keep it updated at all times via 'Update Manager'. But what I've noticed is that if I update today the next day when I log in there is a new set of updates waiting for me.

I want to keep these updates as a backup so I don't have to download the updates all over again if I am forced to freshly install Ubuntu. So what do I Backup?

NOTE: I'm doing this following some random website I visited while surfing the net.
This is what I'm doing (in Terminal) to backup files

```
sudo su
cd /
tar cvpjf backup.tar.bz2 --exclude=/proc --exclude=/lost+found --exclude=/backup.tar.bz2 --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/sys /
```

and to restore it I'm using this (after I put `backup.taz.bz2` in the root location)

```
sudo su
cd /
tar xvpfj backup.tar.bz2 -C /
```

but I'm not sure if this backups the updates...does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If want to backup your updates & installed packages. Just copy `/var/cache/apt/archives` to some another location and copy them back after fresh install. You will save many packages to be re downloaded.

Doing the above would be easy using [AptonCD](http://aptoncd.sourceforge.net/)

Also you can use [remastersys](http://www.remastersys.com/) to create image of your current system and install from it with updated package and installed files. Probably it also keeps track of your settings. I'm not sure about the last feature.

Comment: By "backup your installed packages" do you mean that when I paste the files in /var/cache/apt/archives (after fresh install) I wont have to install the softwares I had (before the fresh install) OR it just stores the list of files (names) so that after copying it will start downloading those softwares?

Comment: It will just store the file (not the list name). It won't install automatically. Now whenever you install a software, if the software was previously installed and not updated in between, the package will not be downloaded.If the software is updated it will be downloaded. (Say in server the version is v0.3 and you have installed v0.2 previously) Its more like, if you are uninstalling a software and reinstalling it.